# powershell execution policy unrestriction is not accepitng

Tags: powershell, nodemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfkQ5.png)

<i have tried removing the **restriction** but at the end powershell isnt acceptiong Y as a command its showing error [y] its repeating the same statement >

Comment: Hello @Karthik and welcome.  It would be helpful to include an exact repeatable example of the commands you ran that produced the results you mentioned. Also include a copy of the exact error received. Based on what you wrote the problem sounds like you were not running PowerShell as an Administrator. TO do this right click on the link to PowerShell and select Run as Administrator then try your command again. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Run the powershell as administrator.

2.Run following command

*Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted*